# Mako variable not being passed into pyramid form properly

Tags: python, pyramid, mako

I have a mako form that includes a variable to be passed in as the value for a hidden form tag. Somehow, the variable is not being passed properly. This code has been working before, but now the html generated does not render the value properly.

Mako code:

```
<b>Create model at path</b>: ${ppath}
<%def name="direct_load_model_form(method, ppath)">
${h.tags.form(method, multipart=True, method='post', hidden_fields=[('ppath', ppath)])}
<b>Node Name: </b>${h.tags.text('node_name')}<BR>
<b>Parameters: </b>${h.tags.file('params_file', size=100)}<BR>
${h.tags.submit('submit', 'Create')}
${h.tags.end_form()}
</%def>

${self.direct_load_model_form(process_route, ppath)}
```

The hidden_fields function is from the web helpers library. In my views, I am trying to use `ppath` as `ppath = self.request.POST['ppath']`.

The `ppath` variable renders correctly in the first line but not when passed as the value to a hidden field. Do I need to escape it another time or something?

This is the html rendered:

```
<input type="hidden" value="" name="ppath">
```

Comment: I don't think the problem is with Mako here. It's probably the way you use your form library, which you don't specify in your question. To help you debug, you could try `${ppath}` in your def somewhere. Also, you could directly write your hidden input: `<input type="hidden" value="${ppath}" name="ppath">`.

Comment: I updated my question. I'm pretty sure the template code worked before. I think I may write the hidden input directly, but hidden_fields is great convenience method when I have more than one value. I would probably write my own method.

Comment: Can you put up a simplified version of your view code so we can see how you're actually passing ppath to the template and mention which version of webhelpers you're using?

Comment: also can you post an expected result?

Answer (score 1):

Here is something you could try, instead of using ppath everywhere, you could rename ppath in your def function to path.

```
<b>Create model at path</b>: ${ppath}

<%def name="direct_load_model_form(method, path)">
   ${h.tags.form(method, multipart=True, method='post', hidden_fields=[('ppath', path)])}
   <b>Node Name: </b>${h.tags.text('node_name')}<BR>
   <b>Parameters: </b>${h.tags.file('params_file', size=100)}<BR>
   ${h.tags.submit('submit', 'Create')}
   ${h.tags.end_form()}
</%def>

${self.direct_load_model_form(process_route, ppath)}
```

It might be an issue but since mako creates python code, it's possible that somewhere, the parameter sent to your function is being overriden. That said it's unclear which variable it will use since defs can access global variables but you reset while calling the def.